# PaperCut URL Redirect

Tags: redirect

As part of papercut byod setup, I want the students to go to http://byodprint.mydomain.edu and be redirected to http://papercut.mydomain.edu:9163/setup. How is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: Sure, just set up a webserver at byodprint.mydomain.edu and configure it to perform your redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Easier than a redirect would be to change the listening port to port 80.  See the following article: https://www.papercut.com/kb/Main/RunningOnPort80

Answer (score 0):

There is no "easy" way to do this. As your first commenter suggested, you will need to set up a web server somewhere to perform the redirect. There are a variety of solutions available for this.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/324000/how-to-redirect-urls-to-different-web-sites

https://github.com/dotzero/node-url-shortener